# Setting years in x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have coded the following program with matplotlib to graph no.of elements with time.

```
import pylab
import numpy as np
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, MonthLocator, DateFormatter

date1 = datetime.date(1995, 1, 1)
date2 = datetime.date(2004, 4, 12)

years = YearLocator()   # every year
months = MonthLocator()  # every month
yearsFmt = DateFormatter('%Y')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
ax.autoscale_view()

pylab.ylim(0, 250)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(0,250,6,endpoint=True))

pylab.xlabel('YEAR')
pylab.ylabel('No. of sunspots')
pylab.title('SUNSPOT VS YEAR GRAPH')

a=[[50,50],[100,100],[250, 250],[200,200],[150,150]]
plt.plot(*zip(*a), marker='o', color='r', ls='')
```

The output is as follows

[image]

However,I was expecting it to display years instead of numbers in x-axis.

Comment: For the date locator/formatter to work correctly you need to plot against `datetime` objects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *are* plotting years, but the years are 50, 100, 250, 200, and 150. These are the first element in the lists inside of `a`, which is passed to pyplot.plot as the `x` values.

You want to define your dates somewhere, though you'll also probably want to set the `xticks` to be the same as the dates you're plotting, as I can tell you care about the graph looking neat.

```
import pylab
import numpy as np
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator, MonthLocator, DateFormatter
```

Also, don't forget to import `pyplot`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Here are some example dates. You can change them to whatever exact date you have for the sunspot measurements.

```
a=[[datetime.date(1995, 1, 1),  50],
   [datetime.date(2000, 1, 1), 100],
   [datetime.date(2005, 1, 1), 250],
   [datetime.date(2010, 1, 1), 200],
   [datetime.date(2015, 1, 1), 150]
  ]

years = YearLocator()   # every year
months = MonthLocator()  # every month
yearsFmt = DateFormatter('%Y')
```

Call `gca` to get current axis before you modify the axis.

```
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
ax.autoscale_view()

pylab.ylim(0, 250)
plt.yticks(np.linspace(0,250,6,endpoint=True))
```

Pick out the dates from the `a` array to use them as xtick labels.

```
dates = [date for date,sunspot in a]
plt.xticks(dates)

pylab.xlabel('YEAR')
pylab.ylabel('No. of sunspots')
pylab.title('SUNSPOT VS YEAR GRAPH')

plt.plot(*zip(*a), marker='o', color='r', ls='')
plt.show()
```

[image: pyplot output]