# How to show years in x-axis using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have date-wise data to plot but not all consecutive dates available. However, on x-axis I have to show years only. I have tried set_major_locator, YearLocator, MonthLocator etc but it didnt work. Also, I made sure to have dates in datetime format.

After trying these, still some years are missing in graph as marked in below screen shot.

Output:
[Graph screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukKVz.png)

Code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(len(dates)))
ax1.set_xticklabels(dates)
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',rotation=90, zorder=120)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(1,month=1,day=1)) 
plt.plot(dates,baseData.Sabic, linewidth=3)
plt.plot(dates,baseData.PriceDivReinv, linewidth=3)
plt.plot(dates,baseData.PricePlusAccDividend, linewidth=3)
ax1.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

Also, i am unable to get year only using datetime.DateFormatter('%Y')

So, i need help with showing all available years in x-axis.

Comment: Try it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253658/python-matplotlib-setting-years-in-x-axis). He has only years in his x-axis.

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example. We can't run your code, since we don't have neither dates, nor baseData. We don't really need the real data. Just some dummy ones for the minimal reproducible example. That don't even really need to have ``Sabic``, ``PriceDivReinv`` etc: one trace is enough, since your question is obviously not about having multiple lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xtics are supposed to contain location on the x axis. And on the xaxis you have dates. So, xtics are supposed to be dates. But you filled it with numbers (from arange) that will match nothing.

I am even surprised that you get what you described, since you should have got not labels at all.

So, you are not using `ax1.set_xticks` and `ax1.set_xtickslabels` right. And, anyway, I don't think you need them here. Just remove those two lines, and, as far as I can tell without a reproducible example, you should be ok.

My own minimal reproducible example of what I understand of your problem and its solution

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import YearLocator

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
ax1 = plt.subplot(111)
dates=[datetime.datetime(2005,1,1)+i*datetime.timedelta(days=10) for i in range(300)]
ax1.tick_params(axis='x',rotation=90, zorder=120)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(YearLocator(1,month=1,day=1))
plt.plot(dates,np.sin(0.1*np.arange(300)), linewidth=3)
ax1.margins(x=0)
plt.show()
```

It plots a curve of whatever, with dates on the x-axis, and years as labels.

Comment: It worked for me by removing  `_xticks ` and  `set_xtickslabels` , and keeping dates in date format.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to reformate your ax1.set_xticklabels() to yearly strings?

Well since I dont know what your data looks like I am just gonna do with a list comprehension with a bunch of strings

```
import datetime as dt
dates = ['22-7-1997','1-12-1996','17-06-1992','10-09-1999']
dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%d-%m-%Y").year for date_string in dates]
# Will give you only years
```

After that just pass your list as an argument in `ax1.set_xticklabels(dates)`